# Converting list to data frame doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having difficulty in converting lists into dataframe after a loop. I was getting results for the first 3 lines, however the rest of the output are NaN values.
Here's my code. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

```
    for i in range(0,5000):
        data=data_phished["url"][i]
        if not urlparse(data).scheme:
            url = 'https://' + data
        print(i),print(url)

    urlRequest.append(fe.urlRequest(url,soup,hostname))
    urlAnchor.append(fe.urlAnchor(url,soup,hostname))
    linksTags.append(fe.linksTags(url))
    sfh.append(fe.sfh(url,soup,hostname))
    emailSubmit.append(fe.emailSubmit(url))
    urlAbnormal.append(fe.urlAbnormal(url,hostname))

    #Storing extracted features in a list
    label = []
    for i in range(0,5000):
        label.append(1)

    #Converting the list to dataframe

    feat_col = {'request_url':pd.Series(urlRequest), 'anchor_url':pd.Series(urlAnchor),'links_in_tags':pd.Series(linksTags),'server_from_handler':pd.Series(sfh),'submit_info_email':pd.Series(emailSubmit),'abnormal_url':pd.Series(urlAbnormal),'class':pd.Series(label)}

    abn = pd.DataFrame(feat_col)
    abn
```

And this is the ouput I'm getting (attached)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMWwB.png

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with the purpose of this site.
Your posted code does not run.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't really need to use pd.Series inside the `feat_col` dict.

```py
feat_col = {'request_url':urlRequest, 'anchor_url':urlAnchor,'links_in_tags':linksTags,'server_from_handler':sfh,'submit_info_email':emailSubmit,'abnormal_url':urlAbnormal,'class':label}
```

should suffice. And I think you should indent feature collection part after for loop:

```
    for i in range(0,5000):
        data=data_phished["url"][i]
        if not urlparse(data).scheme:
            url = 'https://' + data
        print(i),print(url)

        # These lines should be indented to be run in the for loop.
        urlRequest.append(fe.urlRequest(url,soup,hostname))
        urlAnchor.append(fe.urlAnchor(url,soup,hostname))
        linksTags.append(fe.linksTags(url))
        sfh.append(fe.sfh(url,soup,hostname))
        emailSubmit.append(fe.emailSubmit(url))
        urlAbnormal.append(fe.urlAbnormal(url,hostname))
```

---

**Edit**: Final code

```py
    label = []
    for i in range(0,5000):
        data=data_phished["url"][i]
        if not urlparse(data).scheme:
            url = 'https://' + data
        print(i),print(url)

        try:
            # These lines should be indented to be run in the for loop.
            urlRequest.append(fe.urlRequest(url,soup,hostname))
            urlAnchor.append(fe.urlAnchor(url,soup,hostname))
            linksTags.append(fe.linksTags(url))
            sfh.append(fe.sfh(url,soup,hostname))
            emailSubmit.append(fe.emailSubmit(url))
            urlAbnormal.append(fe.urlAbnormal(url,hostname))
            label.append(1)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Some error")

    feat_col = {'request_url':urlRequest, 'anchor_url':urlAnchor,'links_in_tags':linksTags,'server_from_handler':sfh,'submit_info_email':emailSubmit,'abnormal_url':urlAbnormal,'class':label}
    abn = pd.DataFrame(feat_col)
    abn
```

Comment: Thanks @armamut, I tried this, I indent the code, but I got this error: URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>

Comment: one of your url's should be broken,unreachable or corrupt. try using `try: except:` block around url parts

Comment: I've tried the final code, and thanks so much for helping me however, still getting the same error

Comment: the script without try: except: worked. however, whenever I rerun the code, to restart the kernel, it gives me an error. I'm using jupyter notebook in visual studio code

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to convert from dict to dataframe. For that you must use .from_dict

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(feat_col)
```

Comment: Thanks @anik jha. I tried this but got this output:                                            

0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1

Comment: Can you please share the head and dimension of values of feat_col_dict
Also, for starters you can try if the following works: 
```abn['request_url']=urlRequest
abn['anchor_url']=urlAnchor

See if it works

Comment: you don't HAVE to use .from_dict.. you can just pass a dict into the pd.DataFrame constructor